# Divs are not floating left

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a form and a container div. The container div looks like this:

#### CONTAINER

```
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
```

And then inside container I have divs with classes of panel:

#### PANEL

```
.panel {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
```

But for some reason the the panel is not floating to the end of it's container?

Here is full html

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<%= form_with(model: fee_change_submission, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="panel">
    <%= form.label :account_name, class: "panel__top-label" %>
    <%= form.text_field :account_name, class: "panel__top-input" %>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
  <%= form.label :account_number, class: "panel__top-label" %>
  <%= form.text_field :account_number, class: "panel__top-input" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 500px;

      h1 {
        text-align: left;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      }

      // All Forms
      form {
        .panel {
          width: 50%;
          float: left;

          &__top-input {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
          }

          &__top-label {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
            color: $gray-color;
          }

          .btn {
            width: 100px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

#### SCREENSHOT:

[image]

Here is a picture of the problem. As you can see, I have set the width to to 50% but it's not floating to the left.

Comment: Can you please provide the compiled CSS instead and maybe turn your code into a runnable snippet instead? Alternatively, maybe show a screenshot of how it currently looks like and explain what’s wrong with it?

Comment: Yea, I can provide a picture. I'm not sure how to find the compiled CSS though

Comment: You should be able to see it when you run this in your browser?

Comment: the `'.container'` class is conspicuously absent from your HTML snippet

Comment: fixed @McHat sorry about that

Comment: so the first panel "account name" is behaving differently than the other panels?

Comment: No they are all behaving the same. None of them will float right if you give them a different size

Comment: I have zero clue how it should actually look like. The code you have given us (even when compiled) does not help at all to reproduce this, and it’s really difficult to tell anything without seeing more. Please provide a [mcve] and give us example code (that runs in the browser without having to have another compiler) that reproduces your problem properly.

Comment: in your screenshot "account name" and "account number" panels are behaving differently.  in your code they are styled the same.  something doesn't add up with the example you have given... agree with @poke we need a MCVE to help you with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was "nothing wrong" with your css. I had to remove a scss variable and it would take the styles after that, `color: $gray-color;`. I think the issue was that you didn't know this was scss code, or mabye you did?

```css
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
}
.container h1 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.container .form .panel {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.container .form .panel__top-input {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
.container .form .panel__top-label {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  color: gray;
}
.container .form .panel .btn {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" class="form">
    <div class="panel">
      <label for="" class="panel__top-label" />
      <input type="text" class="panel__top-input" />
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
      <label for="" class="panel__top-label" />
      <input type="text" class="panel__top-input" />
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
      <label for="" class="panel__top-label" />
      <input type="text" class="panel__top-input" />
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
      <label for="" class="panel__top-label" />
      <input type="text" class="panel__top-input" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the edited scss

```
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  h1 {
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .form {
    .panel {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      &__top-input {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }
      &__top-label {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        color: gray; // change this
      }
      .btn {
        width: 100px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [my comment to the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206303/divs-are-not-floating-left#comment79376470_46206303). There is “nothing wrong” with OP’s code because it is not complete enough to highlight their problem. It’s easily possible that some other stylings (e.g. form field margins) cause 50% floats to wrap to another row. But that’s just wild guessing, we don’t even know what the result is *supposed* to look like.

Comment: @poke This is the problem with SO sometimes. If OP provide this code then that is what I'm gone answer on. I'm got the result OP got, by that I mean the style did not apply at all, that is because the scss did not compile correctly (due to variable) Now if you look at the image provided by the OP you can see he/she adds css in devtools on that specific element giving it a width of 50% and a float left. So I don't think my answer is that off, as it probably gives the wanted result and correct reason as to why it did not work based on information provided.